# Error capturing webcam image in matlab

Tags: matlab

I got this error when I tried to capture image using my pc webcam. I am new to matlab. How can I fix this error?

> Error using imaq.VideoDevice
>   No device is available for the specified ADAPTORNAME. See IMAQHWINFO('dcam').
>
> Error in maina1 (line 4)
>   obj =imaq.VideoDevice('dcam', 1, 'YUYV_320x240','ROI', [1 1 320 240]);

This is my code,

```
obj =imaq.VideoDevice('dcam', 1, 'YUYV_320x240','ROI', [1 1 320 240]); set(obj,'ReturnedColorSpace', 'rgb'); figure('menubar','none','tag','webcam');
```

This is the answers I got when I run 'imaqhwinfo' and 'webcamlist'

```
>imaqhwinfo

ans = 

InstalledAdaptors: {'dcam'}
    MATLABVersion: '8.6 (R2015b)'
      ToolboxName: 'Image Acquisition Toolbox'
   ToolboxVersion: '4.10 (R2015b)'

> webcamlist

ans = 

'Integrated Webcam'
```

Comment: "this error"? what error?

Comment: What does `imaqhwinfo('dcam')` return?

Comment: Error using imaq.VideoDevice No device is available for the specified ADAPTORNAME. See IMAQHWINFO('dcam').

Error in maina1 (line 4) obj =imaq.VideoDevice('dcam', 1, 'YUYV_320x240','ROI', [1 1 320 240]);

Comment: You get that error when you run `imaqhwinfo('dcam')`?

Comment: No, I am implementing code to face detection using web cam. It gives error near the imaq.VideoDevice

Comment: Then again, what does `imaqhwinfo('dcam')` return?

Comment: imaqhwinfo('dcam')

ans = 

       AdaptorDllName: 'C:\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2015b\dcamhardware\toolbox\imaq\supportpackages\dcam\adaptor\win64…'
    AdaptorDllVersion: '4.10 (R2015b)'
          AdaptorName: 'dcam'
            DeviceIDs: {1x0 cell}
           DeviceInfo: [1x0 struct]

Comment: Please put that information into your question, it is important. The only adapter installed (dcam) does not recognize your camera.

Comment: Can other applications (for example skype) recognize your webcam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to resolve my error. I haven't downloaded a [support package](http://in.mathworks.com/help/imaq/installing-the-support-packages-for-image-acquisition-toolbox-adaptors.html) for the Image Acquisition Toolbox for my particular camera. When I installed the "OS Generic Video Interface" support package my codes are working.